# Best practice for lazy loading in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have an API that I'm querying where when I query for a list of organizations I get an array of:

```
{ 
    id: integer,
    name: string
}
```

But I am also able to get details on each organization which returns a single object like:

```
{ 
    id: integer,
    name: string,
    description: text,
    visit_count: integer,
    image_url: string
}
```

How would I set up the object(s) in RestKit for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the following:

1. The Object with all the elements you described in your second block
2. An object manager

   ```
   RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR HOST NAME]];
   objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType=RKMIMETypeJSON;
   ```
3. A mapping object with all the elements in your object

   ```
   RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[YOUR CLASS class]];
   ```
4. The mapping for your object

   ```
   [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id",
                                            @"name",
                                            @"description",
                                            @"visit_count",
                                            @"image_url"
                                            ]];
   ```
5. A response descriptor

   ```
   RKResponseDescriptor *responseDesciptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:OBJECT URL keyPath:YOUR KEY PATH statusCodes:nil];
   ```
6. Add the response descriptor to the object manager

   ```
   [objectManager responseDesciptor];
   ```
7. Now you can hit up the server

   ```
   [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil path:OBJECT URL parameters:nil
        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            self.variable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: mappingResult.array];
        }
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

           UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An Error Has Occurred" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [alertView show];

     }];
   ```

Comment: Hopefully it's going to core data do you want an entity mapping and unique identifier (hence you can update a previous stub object). Might want to ask about that...

Comment: +1 you are right. I assumed no core data from the question but might be wrong indeed.